# Getting Active directory users in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, active-directory

How can we take the user's details from active directory in SharePoint 2010. I have one requirement, which has the functionality to send the mail to all the users who are listed in particular column in share point list. These column has the type of Single line of text (displaying display-name of the User). I need to retrieve each users information from AD by passing this display name without adding any LDAP connection string anywhere. Is it possible? if it possible, please help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: Best bet would be to look in the userinfo list, http://zimmergren.net/technical/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list There are however no guarantee any of your users will be listed there. Your question is a perfect example of where you cannot do it the simple way any more, you will most likely have to build a proper integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the best way to achieve this is to use User Profile Synchronization. First you will need to configure [user profile synchronization](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049%28v=office.14%29.aspx) with AD. Then you can use SharePoint API ([UserProfileManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.aspx) class of server object model) to access user properties imported from AD.